# Install Docker script error - permission denied

Tags: docker, centos7

I'm trying to install Docker for CentOS 7 from the documentation but I got permission denied right away:

```
sudo curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
sh: line 241: /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-main.repo: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your command line, you are only executing curl with sudo, not sh. Try this:

```
su -c "curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh"
```

or, if it does not work, e.g. because no root password is set on your system:

```
sudo su -c "curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh"
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW, this probably only works when you `su root` first. Or, run the command as `sudo su -c "curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh"`. That worked for me.

Comment: No, this works if you are able to become root by `su` and will prompt you for the root password. If you aren't (e.g. because no root password is set), your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

the doc at https://docs.docker.com/installation/centos/ begins with "Log into your machine as a user with sudo or root privileges." I guess you should begin with a privileged user, only then you can do `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh`

Comment: I think the error is with the docker docs, and that statement should be changed to "Log into your machine as a user with **root** privileges.". As described by @anderas above, sudo privileges doesn't affect the ability to pass `sudo` to the `sh`after the pipe. Luckily, the workaround is fairly straightforward.